# Image in Navigation Bar Breaks Vertically Centered Text

Tags: html, css, image, navbar, vertical-alignment

I have this nav bar:

```
<div id="nav">
 <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
 <a href="#"><img src="assets/zslogoblack.png"></a>
 <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Styled as so:

```
#nav {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
}
#nav a {
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 33%;
}
#nav a:first-of-type,#nav a:last-of-type {
 line-height: 60px;
}
#nav img {
 height: 60px;
}
```

Here is the output
[image: screenshot (with borders and computed heights added)]
I need everything to be vertically aligned within a fixed navbar that is 60px tall, but for some reason, this is not happening. I thought the problem was caused by

```
line-height:60px;
```

being applied to the anchor that contained the image, hence the

```
#nav a:first-of-type,#nav a:last-of-type {
 line-height: 60px;
}
```

But that did not fix the problem. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'display:flex;' to '#nav':

```
#nav
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Here is a working example:

```css
#nav {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 display:flex;
 align-items: center;
}
#nav a {
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 33%;
}
#nav a:first-of-type,#nav a:last-of-type {
 line-height: 60px;
}
#nav img {
 height: 60px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="nav">
     <a href="#">Portfolio</a><a href="#"><img src="/" style="background:#000;width:50px;"></a><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
```